# Sum of all nodes in a binary tree (Logic only: theory please)

Tags: sum, binary-tree, nodes

Hey I just would like to understand the answer theoretically i.e. the logic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sample Binary Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPGYo.png)

Binary tree being a recursive data structure... for the above image, you can follow the convention to go left till you reach the end and come back from the sub nodes and finally go towards the right side of the parent node. Basically left side[from our view and right side from viewpoint of node] has more priority than right while summing up.

for the image above..
the sum would be A+B+D+C+E+F

Hope that helps

Comment: If you are satisfied, could you upvote me? Since I'm a beginner looking to gain more access :)